# Difference between getUnderContent and getOverContent of itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am working on a task where I need to write few details in the pdf.
My earlier code was:

```
public void addTextOnPDF(final List<String> textString,
                                             final File pdfFile,
                                             final File destination) throws Exception {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath());
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
                new FileOutputStream(destination.getAbsolutePath()));
        float x, y;
        com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle pagesize;
        com.itextpdf.text.Font font = new com.itextpdf.text.Font(com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10);
        font.setColor(BaseColor.RED);
        for(int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            pagesize = reader.getPageSize(i);
            PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(i);
            x = pagesize.getLeft(10);
            y = pagesize.getHeight() - (pagesize.getHeight() - 50);
            for(String text : textString) {
                ColumnText.showTextAligned(content, Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM, Phrase.getInstance(0, text, font), x, y, 0);
                y = y - 10;
            }
        }
        pdfStamper.close();
    }
```

For some pdf, the above code was working fine. But it is not working for all pdf.
When I change the method from getUnderContent to getOverContent, it is working great for all the pdf files.
I try to find out the difference between the method getUnderContent and getOverContent in the itext documentation and there is this definition given in it. [itext definition](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.13/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html)

```
getUnderContent: Gets a PdfContentByte to write under the page of the original document.
getOverContent: Gets a PdfContentByte to write over the page of the original document.
```

My question is how the getUnderContent and getOverContent works on pdf?
If I use getUnderContent then why it was not failed on all the pdfs and only for a few pdf.
Where to use getUnderContent and getOverContent?

Answer (score 2):

*To describe this with more detail:*

The static content of a PDF page is drawn by a sequence of instructions. Later instructions draw over what earlier instructions drew.

These instructions are contained in a single stream or in the concatenation of a number of streams in an array associated with the page.

The `UnderContent` and the `OverContent` offer two ways of adding instructions to this sequence: The former adds a new stream for your additions at the start of the content streams array, the latter adds one at the end.

When you want to add extra static content to a page, whether to add it to the `UnderContent` or the `OverContent`, depends on the nature of the additions and the kind of PDF you add it to.

Usually you add background material (like stuff normally supplied by preprinted stationary paper) to the `UnderContent` and stamp-like material to the `OverContent`.

*Some words of warning:*

Beware, though: In contrast to stationary paper used with typewriters where you could be sure that the stationary content remains visible (unless the user does a lot of typing or tippexing), PDFs from the wild sometimes as first page content instructions fill a page-sized rectangle in white, covering anything you might put into the `UnderContent` without a visible trace.

So while something like a watermark would at first glance be considered background material to be added to the `UnderContent`, you may actually want to put it into the `OverContent`, probably with a degree of transparency, unless you can be sure that your input PDF don't hide everything drawn before.

If you are trying to create PDF/A documents, though, the situations differs as such transparency effects are forbidden there. Very subtle, opaque `OverContent` watermarks here still is an option but massive ones would make the watermarked PDF unreadable.

*As an aside:*

Actually the description above, *adding an additional stream at the start or the end of the content streams array,* is a bit simplified. iText additionally adds some instructions wrapping new and existing contents so that usually your additions have no unwanted side effects on the existing content and vice versa. E.g. if you selected a red fill color in the `UnderContent` while the original content expects the default black red fill color to be set, your color selection does not bleed through.

Answer (score 1):

The name says it all. You already have a PDF file and If you want to post something under the page content you can use `getUnderContent()`, but this won't be visible at all times as this will overlapped with the actual contents in your pdf.

If you use `getOverContent()`, this will be written over the existing contents in your pdf and thus being top layer will be visible at all times, eg: Watermark